# some of the value of weblements in list of webelement are coming blank How to wait for each value of webelement to appear in webelements in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

```
ArrayList<String> corousalItems= new ArrayList<>();
List<WebElement>  listText=  driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("CorousalList"));
for (WebElement list : listText) {
    String text=list.getText();
    corousalItems.add(text);
}
System.out.println("List :"+corousalItems);
```

Some of the elements of above list are coming blank as  value of those webelements are taking time to load.Need a way where driver can wait for the value to appear which can be added in the list.

Only 3 images are shown on corousal. On clicking next bottom , corousal scrolls horizontally to 1 image. But on using CorousalList selector, able to locate the text that appears on corousal without clicking next button. The only issue is that some of the values are not loading so blank value is storing in list.

Answer (score 1):

You were close. To locate the desired elements you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy()` and you can use the following solution:

```
ArrayList<String> corousalItems= new ArrayList<>();
List<WebElement>  listText=  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("CorousalList")));
for (WebElement list : listText) {
    String text=list.getText();
    corousalItems.add(text);
}
System.out.println("List :"+corousalItems);
```

Comment: Getting this exceptionn on trying the above code... org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of all elements located by By.cssSelector: CorousalList (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Comment: I have always used `cssSelector()`, but in your code trials it seems to be **`cssSelection()`**, can you replace `cssSelector()` with **`cssSelection()`**, run your tests and let me know the results please?

Comment: Only 3 images are shown on corousal. On clicking next bottom , corousal scrolls horizontally to 1 image. But on using CorousalList selector, able to locate the text that appears on corousal without clicking next button. The only issue is that some of the values are not loading so blank value is storing in list

Comment: Instead of comments you need to update the main question with all these information along with the relevant HTML.

Comment: cssSelection() is not compiling

Comment: Cant post HTML as its confidential

Comment: sorry I used cssSelection in post but actually using cssSelector in my IDE which is still not working with yor solution

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:enter code here

```
ArrayList<String> corousalItems= new ArrayList<>();
    List<WebElement>  listText=  driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("CorousalList"));
    for (WebElement list : listText) {
    wait.until((ExpectedCondition<Boolean>)driver->{
    String text=list.getText();
    return text.equals("")? false:true;
    });

        corousalItems.add(text);
    }
    System.out.println("List :"+corousalItems);
```

Comment: Line corousalItems.add(text); is giving compiler error with a message text is "cannot resolve symbol text"

Comment: Tried declaring string text before expectedcondition but then variable text inside expectedcondition code block is giving error variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively final